# How to create a vf page as same as standard email send page

Tags: emailmessage

I need to create a vf page exactly like in this image. Everything , should be there including the lookup property of the fields. But when i tried creating , bcc address and cc address are text only(reference from EmailMessage object).
Will it be possible ? [image]

Comment: This is a good size task as you have to implement an email template selector and then use the (fortunately added in Summer 16) template renderer methods plus an attach file(s) dialog

Answer (score 0):

Email addresses are actually stored as strings, so using a text field to input them is not a concern. What you do need to be aware of is that you'll need to append a comma after each email address (ideally before each additional one that follows after the 1st) if there's going to be more than one in the CC or BCC list as a separator for your email handler class to be able to process them correctly.